# Able to see Dialog box opened on all pages when redirected

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a page where i have two tabs i.e 'Staffing' and 'Non Staffing' .When i click on 'Staffing' tab then i'm redirected to a page1 and when i click on 'Non Staffing' tab i'm redirected to a page2 .I have a button inside page2 and when i click on that button i gets a dialog box i.e Iteration1 Suppose if i don't close my dialog box i.e Iteration1 which has been opened on page2 and then if click on tab 'Staffing' i can see the same dialog box i.e Iteration1 opened on page1 also .So how can I hide dialog box with the navigation to different pages?

Sample code here(http://jsfiddle.net/CPtp4/18/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event of the tab control, and from within it call the dialog's [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) method if the tab just activated is not the one that contains the dialog.

Comment: I'm still wondering where to use close method.Kindly check my code then you would be able to help me more .

Comment: @Anuj: Just after `$('#abc1').hide();`.